# ambiguous variable in a class instance

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Novice question. Let's say that I've created a simple list typeclass that takes two strings and adds their respective elements if they're integers or concatenates them if they're strings:

```
class NewList a where
    addLists :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]

instance NewList Int where
    addLists = addNumLists 

addNumLists :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
addNumLists (x : xs) (y : ys) = x + y : addNumLists xs ys
addNumLists _ _ = []

instance NewList Char where
    addLists x y = concat [x,y]
```

This compiles, but if I run `addLists [1,2,3] [1,2,3]` in GHCi I get the error

```
<interactive>:278:11:
Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraints:
  (Num a0) arising from the literal `1' at <interactive>:278:11
  (NewList a0)
    arising from a use of `addLists' at <interactive>:278:1-8
Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
In the expression: 1
In the first argument of `addLists', namely `[1, 2, 3]'
In the expression: addLists [1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3]
```

Adding `:: [Int]` to the expression allows it to be evaluated, but I don't understand why the error appears in the first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the default for [integral literal numbers](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-790004.3.4) is `Integer`, and not `Int`:

> #### 4.3.4 Ambiguous Types, and Defaults for Overloaded Numeric Operations
>
> [...]
>
> Only one default declaration is permitted per module, and its effect is limited to that module. If no default declaration is given in a module then it assumed to be:
>
> ```
>   default (Integer, Double)
> ```

Note that you can fix this easily if you change the type of `addNumLists` and add the `Integer` instance:

```
-- We don't need `Int`, we only need `+`, so anything that is `Num` should work
addNumLists :: (Num a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
addNumLists (x : xs) (y : ys) = x + y : addNumLists xs ys
addNumLists _ _ = []

instance NewList Integer where
    addLists = addNumLists
```